# Adding members to google group in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-groups

I am trying to add members to google group using the python script as shown below. I am using a service account to add members to a group. However, I am getting the below error:

Error:

```
An error occurred: ('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', {'error': 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': 'Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.'})
```

python script:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from pathlib import Path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import os
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
CREDENTIAL_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "python-demo-project-service-account.json")

print(CREDENTIAL_PATH)

# Path to your service account key file
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = CREDENTIAL_PATH

# The email of the Google Group to modify
GROUP_EMAIL = 'email.com'

# The email of the user to add to the group
USER_EMAIL = 'user@domain.com'

# Scopes required for the Directory API
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member']

def add_user_to_group(service_account_file, group_email, user_email):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        service_account_file, scopes=SCOPES)

    # You need to specify the subject email if you're using domain-wide delegation
    # This is the email of a user in the domain with sufficient permissions to add members to a group
    delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('user@domain.com')

    service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)

    member = {
        'email': user_email,
        'role': 'MEMBER'
    }

    try:
        result = service.members().insert(groupKey=group_email, body=member).execute()
        print(f'Added {user_email} to {group_email}: {result}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred: {e}')

# Add a user to the group
add_user_to_group(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, GROUP_EMAIL, USER_EMAIL)
```

Can someone help me what permissions my service accounts needs or am I missing something.

Comment: Insufficient information. Also, this is not a programming question appropriate for StackOverflow. At least as written since we have no idea what permissions the Google account you are using has. Given the error is seems safe to conclude your account does not have the required permissions. Is there some reason you think the error is due to a bug in your code rather than an issue involving the (lack of) permissions your account has to perform the operation?